# Prevent Subwindow Resize

Tags: qt

:D

I'm a Qt beginner and I have some problems.

Generally, all the languages and tools that have an GUI builder have for the window the "Resizeable" property.
Very well, I need to do the same in Qt:
No window resize, no resize pointer in hover the window's border, maximize button (in the window's title) disabled.

I'm tried to find something but unsuccessfully.

If someone help me, I'll be grateful.

Hug.

Sorry for my english. I'm brazilian. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `void QWidget::setWindowFlags ( Qt::WindowFlags type )`.  
see [enum Qt::WindowType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt.html#WindowType-enum) for the list of flags you can play with.

For instance, setting `Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint` should produce a windows without resize frame and no max/min button.

Comment: Very good. It works. :D Thank you very much. If have some time, try to help me on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656893/qrc-file-ui-file-does-not-work

Answer (score 3):

In Qt Creator, I think you can create a non-resizable window by giving it the same minimum and maximum size.

Or you can do it by code using `setFixedSize`. In that case, just add this line in your window's constructor:

```
setFixedSize(size());
```

Comment: The initial size in the constructor isn't meaningful. Better use sizeHint()

Comment: In Qt, the initial size is the one set in Qt Creator, which is what he needs here.

Comment: That's just a random size and won't take into account platform-dependent size constraints, font sizes, etc.